# Redirect 301 in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have to do a 301 redirect from a domain with NO **www** to the one with **www** like:

example.com -> 301 -> www.example.com (same domain)

I've bee looking to this example in the [official doumentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-redirects), but it seems like the configuration doesn't considerate the whole URL path, is there any way to accomplish this?

I'm thinking about creating a separate project for **the domain without www** and create a **firebase cloud function** that takes all requests and do a redirect from there

is that the way to go? any simpler solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redirect out f the box in firebase an option I haven't noticed you just go to the following options:

- Hosting
- Connect domain
- You can write your domain like **"example.com"** without www
- Select the **Redirect** check button
- Write your redirect destination, in my case, is the same domain with www

That's it!

[image: 301-redirect-firebase]

Comment: Can you un-accept my answer and accept your own? I think your solution is much better in the context of Firebase (although my answer should also work, that's why I'm reluctant to completely delete it).

Comment: Don't delete your answer, it's a fair approach as well, I'll mark mine later, thanks for the help!

Comment: I cant get goDaddy to redirect so i am doing the firebase redirect BUT is it 301?

Answer (score 2):

*A more [specific solution for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50992126/1308883) (and registrar-agnostic) was provided by Jack himself.*

This is usually accomplished at the domain registrar level rather than at the app level. If your domain is with Google Domains, [these would be the steps](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141).

**Edit:**

Since you have your domain in GoDaddy, I would suggest to follow [the instructions on their help center](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forward-or-mask-your-domain-or-subdomain-422).

Comment: I have domain hosted in godaddy

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to the instructions for that registrar.